# Как сравнить данные с таблицы и выводить результат?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

Приветствую всех, у меня такая задача есть вот такая таблица https://igroteka.club/game/index.html наличие товара и есть главная страница сайта там представлен весь товар, как сделать так чтобы на главной странице выводился товар только тот который есть в таблице ? может какой то скрипт есть чтоб по названию сравнивал все и если названия совпадают то выводил результат. сразу скажу знаний не очень я только учусь а проест доделать надо, спасибо за внимания.

Comment: У вас таблица только на сайте или есть БД с данными? Каким образом выводится таблица на сайт?

Comment: Таблица просто конвертированная с екселя в html. БД есть вот так выглядит полностью товар https://igroteka.club/, я уже думал может айди присвоить какой то к таблице и к товарам на сайте

Comment: ну если загрузить из экселя  таблицу в БД - можно сделать Join с каталогом, а иначе надо как-то объединять на фронтэнде - тут я не помогу

Comment: Просто таблица обновляется несколько раз на день , так же и на главной хочется чтоб показывало только то что есть в таблице

Comment: Может сделать просто по типу галереи картинок товара и каждую картинку привязать к значению в таблице и тех значений которых в таблице нет они выводиться не будут ?